# Rendering 3D map in pgAdmin 4 to view Data?

Tags: postgis, geodjango, geography, 3d-map, pgadmin-4

I found this error `3D geometrics not rendered` in view data (pgAdmin 4).
In GeoDjango I've updated my **PointField** model with **dim=3**. After successful migration, I cannot see my data in map.

**My Django Model is:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.db.models import Manager as GeoManager

class Location(models.Model):
    lat_long = gis_models.PointField( srid=4326, null=True, spatial_index=True, geography=True, dim=3)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'
```

[image]

Comment: I think you are going to have to give a lot more information for someone to help you. What does you data look like, for a start? Are you following some tutorial? Did it work before?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  You can [edit] your question to add additional info such as details about your data, any screenshots that may help explain your problem, what you've tried etc.

Comment: Hi @JohnPowell I'm completly new to this field (gis) and in Postgres as well. I've just created a PointField in django model and changed dimension to 3(To store altitude as well). While view data in pgAdmin i got this error. I'm not following any specific tutorial. I'm learning by search.

Comment: pgAdmin was not designed for 3D geometry viewing. There are countless tools for this. A couple of suggestions, cesiumjs, in a web environment or matplotlib in Python.

Comment: You can always use ST_Force2D to create another column for viewing purposes, which will at least allow you to see the 2D extent of your geometries.

Comment: @Midavalo. I don't really think that this is unclear. OP is asking why he can't see a 3D geometry in the pgAdmin 4 viewer. The answer being that only 2D is implemented, for fairly obvious reasons.

Comment: what will be the best option to see my data in 3D. I've gone through Cesium.Cartographic. But don't know how to use for my DB